# Alter form of formset data before redisplay

Tags: django, django-forms

We have forms cleaned_data and forms instances, I dont know what django uses if I prefer to redisplay the form and dont know how to update suggested attributes.

Planning to do some business logic after validation and redisplay it.

```
if formset.is_valid():
    #do something with forms in formset and redisplay it.
    #maybe, alter forms data 
    return render(.....)
```

How can I change the form values and redisplay it to the user after validation.
All the examples I saw , does change values of form instance then save it to db. I prefer to show it back to the user after alteration.

My real code, simplified.

This is not working.

```
if formset.is_valid():
    formset.forms[0]['price'] = 15        
    return render(.....)
```

This is not working either.

```
if formset.is_valid():
    setattr(formset.forms[0],'price',15)       
    return render(.....)
```

This is not working either.

```
if formset.is_valid():
    setattr(formset.forms[0].instance,'price',15)       
    return render(.....)
```

They all renders the same, not price = 15 formsets.

Update -------->

```
if formset.is_valid():
    formset.data['formset_prefix-0-price'] = 15
```

This makes formset's first form to render with price 15, but since instance is not modified, when I save the form, it is beeing saved with previous value.

I need a proper way to modify formset, after is_valid. To reshow the form or save it afterwards.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Haken , I edited my question, I hope its clear now.

Comment: The conventional way to handle a successful form submission is to redirect to a different page. But you don't have to do that. What have you tried? Can you post your real code? It's hard to understand what your problem is from that code sample.

Comment: although its valid form submission, my form has a actualize submit button, this button should validate and alter some of data after validation and return the same form to the user, without saving the form. i.e. say, I calculate sub total field, using price and quantity fields. I tried clean methods but that just wont do